# How should Application-centric Entities be handled in Domain Driven Design (DDD)?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am reading Eric Evans' DDD book. It seems to me that the philosophy of DDD is to design and develop software architecture centered around the domain, aiming to express the domain in a concise and clear manner. However, I have a question. In reality, software not only needs to solve problems specific to a certain domain but also has to implement various application requirements. For example, in a product system, there may be requirements to register products through Excel uploads and to view the history of such uploads.

If that's the case, we would need objects like 'Excel Upload History' that are unrelated to the product domain. Is the 'Excel Upload History' Entity a Domain Entity? In my opinion, it should be considered an 'Application Entity.' Also, should this 'Excel Upload History' Entity belong to the product domain package? If there are any good articles or opinions on this topic, please share them.

If the examples are not clear, it may be more accurate to refer to tables or logic required for system operations, even though they are not directly related to the domain problem

Answer (score 0):

not an answer, just some thoughts:

Is the "Excel Upload History" part of your ubiquitous language? Is the business using this term and is it part of a process/decision-making defined in your business department. If you drew a diagram of your business process with something like Domain Story Telling, would this "Excel Upload History" appear on it?

Next thing to consider: Is it only part of your adapter? If the Excel Upload was a separate module / hexagon / etc. and those services would bring data into your actual domain, then would it include something like the "Excel Upload History" or is it only something the adapter is concerned with?

So let me phrase a suggestion: I believe the "Excel Upload History" is part of the adapter. But it sounds like you need something like a "Product Registration History". And that would be part of your domain model and therefore a domain entity. It could be that there is a slight difference between those two. If you upload the same exact Excel, you might create a new "Excel Upload History Entry", but it would probably not create a new "Product Registration History Entry".